# JavaScript sending empty parameters to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I am attempting to create a user area for a website that is accessed by using a username and password. I am using HTML for the front end, JavaScript for the back end and PHP for the server side. I am using Xampp to run a local server and PHPMyAdmin to host the database.

The HTML Code:

```
<!-- the Login Section -->
    <input type="text" name="userName" placeholder="username" id="usernameBar">
    <input type="password" name="passWord" placeholder="password" id="passwordBar">
    <button id="loginButton" onclick="Login();">Login</button>
    <p id="IncorrectP" title="Incorrect Username or Password" style="display: none">Invalid</p>
```

JavaScript:

```
function Login(){

    //Connect to the PHP:
    var urlConnect = "checkLogin1.php";
    //Get the username and password:
    var usrUsername = document.getElementById("usernameBar").value;
    var usrPassword = document.getElementById("passwordBar").value;

    //Define the parameters to send to php
    var strParameters = "usrUsername="+usrUsername + "usrPassword="+usrPassword + "&sid=" + Math.random();

        //Define the options for the AJAX request
        var objOptions = {
        method: "post",
        parameters: strParameters,
        onSuccess: function(objXHR) {

            //If objXHR. responseText = Tenant:
            if(objXHR.responseText=='Tenant'){

                //Go to tenant space:
                alert("Success! (Tenant)");
                OpenTenantPage();

            } 
            //Else if objXHR.responseText = Staff:
            else if(objXHR.responseText=='Staff'){

                //Go to staff space:
                alert("Success! (Staff)");
                OpenStaffPage();

            }
            //Else if objXHR.responseText = Admin:
            else if(objXHR.responseText=='Admin'){

                //Go to admin space:
                alert("Success! (Admin)");
                OpenAdminPage();

            }
            else{

                //Run IncorrectLogin:
                alert("Error! No User Account Found!");
                IncorrectLogin();

            }
        }
    }

    // define the AJAX request object
    var objRequest = new Ajax.Request(urlConnect,objOptions);

}
```

PHP:

```
<?php

    //Link the username and password:
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "admin", "12345", "realestate") or die ('Connection to database failed: ' . mysql_error());
    //Extract variables for request parameters:
    extract($_REQUEST);

    //Try to log in as a tentant:
    $resTenantUser = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tenants WHERE Username='$usrUsername' AND Password='$usrPassword'") or die(mysql_error());
    //$resTenantUser = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT * FROM tenants WHERE Username='Charb1' AND Password='123456' ") or die(mysql_error());
    //Set intCount to number of rows in result:
    $intCount = mysqli_num_rows($resTenantUser);

    if($intCount == 0){

        echo "Error!";

    }
    else{

        echo "Tenant";

    }

?>
```

I think that the error my be that the JS is not sending the parameters to the PHP or it is sending empty parameters. I cannot seam to find my mistake though.

Comment: check the **developer** tools network tab to see what is actually being sent in the request ...

Comment: Just to improve the discussion: HTML and javascript are your frontend technologies (run on browser); PHP is your backend language (run on server)

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Comment: Additionally, your JavaScript code could be made a lot more minimal and readable by using something like jQuery which has CSS selector functions.

Comment: Moreover, `<button>` by default will submit the page. Either add `type="button"` as attribute, or use `event.preventDefault()` in the JS function to prevent the default behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parameters` must be in [JSON](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_intro.asp) format not in query string format.something like this:
`parameters:{usrUsername: usrUsername , usrPassword:usrPassword , sid : Math.random()}`

Comment: must be in JSON? do you know that this `Ajax.Request` thing is to know that it only accepts JSON for `parameters`? nevermind - good call :p

Comment: @JaromandaX you can tell with `dataType : 'json'` to AJAX your [desired type of data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) but by default value is `JSON`

Comment: It's all good, I realised that `Ajax.Request` was most likely a `prototype.js` thing, so, as I said, "good call"

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in the query params. You missed `&`. Try this way.

```
var strParameters = "usrUsername="+usrUsername + "&usrPassword="+usrPassword + "&sid=" + Math.random();
```

Or

```
var strParameters = {"usrUsername" : usrUsername, "usrPassword" : usrPassword, "sid" : Math.random()}
```